htaccess update with some wired text making 500 Internal error
i'm facing problem in my website when htacces updates my website will have 500 Internal Error and this code i found it in the file

BEGIN WordPress
التعلي�
ات (الأسطر) بين "BEGIN WordPress" و "END WordPress"
ت�
إنشاؤها دينا�
يكيًا، ويجب تعديلها فقط �
ن خلال �
رشحات ووردبريس (WordPress Filters).
أي تغييرات على التعلي�
ات بين هذه العلا�
ات سيت�
الكتابة فوقها.

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 24 hours"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 24 hours"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 24 hours"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 24 hours"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 24 hours"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 24 hours"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 hours"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 24 hours"

Options -Indexes

Header set X-Endurance-Cache-Level "2"
Header set X-nginx-cache "WordPress"


RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ar/wp-login.php /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

END WordPress

when i delete the code here

التعلي�
ات (الأسطر) بين "BEGIN WordPress" و "END WordPress"
ت�
إنشاؤها دينا�
يكيًا، ويجب تعديلها فقط �
ن خلال �
رشحات ووردبريس (WordPress Filters).
أي تغييرات على التعلي�
ات بين هذه العلا�
ات سيت�
الكتابة فوقها.

my website working fine, the problem is this happen for some time and i need to make the process again. I don't know what cause this error.
also i'm using wpml and elementor plugin for my website
when i delete the code here

التعلي�
ات (الأسطر) بين "BEGIN WordPress" و "END WordPress"
ت�
إنشاؤها دينا�
يكيًا، ويجب تعديلها فقط �
ن خلال �
رشحات ووردبريس (WordPress Filters).
أي تغييرات على التعلي�
ات بين هذه العلا�
ات سيت�
الكتابة فوقها.

my website working fine, the problem is this happen for some time and i need to make the process again. I don't know what cause this error.
Edit: this is the full code:
text/x-generic .htaccess.20230809225414.old ( Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines )
# BEGIN Newfold Skip 404 Handling for Static Files
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(robots\.txt|[a-z0-9_\-]*sitemap[a-z0-9_\.\-]*\.(xml|xsl|html)(\.gz)?)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4|html|htm|rtf|rtx|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|avif|avifs|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|webp|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|webm|mpp|otf|_otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|ogv|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|_ttf|wav|wma|wri|woff|woff2|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [L]
</IfModule>
# END Newfold Skip 404 Handling for Static Files
# BEGIN Newfold File Cache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^/wp-content/newfold-page-cache/ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(wordpress_test_cookie|comment_author|wp\-postpass|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle|wp_woocommerce_session_) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cache-Control} ^((?!no-cache).)*$
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/newfold-page-cache/$1/_index.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-content/newfold-page-cache/$1/_index.html [L]
</IfModule>
# END Newfold File Cache
# BEGIN Newfold Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# END Newfold Browser Cache

# BEGIN WordPress
# التعلي�
ات (الأسطر) بين "BEGIN WordPress" و "END WordPress"
# ت�
 إنشاؤها دينا�
يكيًا، ويجب تعديلها فقط �
ن خلال �
رشحات ووردبريس (WordPress Filters).
# أي تغييرات على التعلي�
ات بين هذه العلا�
ات سيت�
 الكتابة فوقها.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 24 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 24 hours"
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Endurance-Cache-Level "1"
    Header set X-nginx-cache "WordPress"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ar/wp-login.php /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


This appears to be talking about the #BEGIN WordPress / #END WordPress comments, and that nothing between them should be changed manually, in Arabic. Did you - or someone else - put this additional Arabic phrasing in there manually? If so, it is probably messing up the parsing of the file content by WordPress, when it gets modified and rewritten. And if not - then it might be that your translation plugin operates on stuff, it should really rather not touch to begin with.

Hi, it is rewritten automatically in the file no one has access to manage or edit other than me, that's why i want to know what Cuse the issue

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Code Updates in the main post
